# Start Tomcat server in Eclipse IDE ( alway say : Name [UserDatabase] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [UserDatabase]

Tags: java

Using : Eclipse IDE 
Database : SQLServer 2014

When start TOMCAT in Eclipse , It console always show that : 
Everyone help me to read it what happen

Thank you

```
SEVERE: Exception looking up UserDatabase under key UserDatabase
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [UserDatabase] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [UserDatabase].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:824)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.startInternal(UserDatabaseRealm.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.startInternal(CombinedRealm.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.startInternal(LockOutRealm.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:933)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:789)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:483)
```

Comment: Did you check the server.xml under conf? Can you post the server.xml?

Comment: <Server port="8006" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>

Comment: <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>

Comment: <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

Comment: <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" initialSize="3" maxActive="10000" maxIdle="80000" maxWait="30000" name="jdbc/designerdb" password="123456" poolPreparedStatements="true" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;instance=BW-PC\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=designerdb_empty_V6" username="sa" validationQuery="select 1"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>

Comment: <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

Comment: Hari Prasad : Server.xml like that above . If you know about this , please share . thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I delete Realm that delare in Server.xml 
- Console : not show again ( Beacause it not in use)

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm. 
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>
```